# how to declare a const pointer that can be used as "this"

Tags: c++, constants

I have a parent XWin class to encapsulate a program's "X-calls".  Once
I've opened the display.  I pass a pointer to the Xwin class that holds all
X-related pointers (resources, display, etc) and all X calls are made
through that class's pointer.

I have separate objects that are passed the handle to the XWin Class so
they can make graphics calls through the wrapper class.

I am trying to declare the pointer a "const"

```
Meter::Meter(const XWin * parent,...): parent_(parent) {}
class Meter {...
    Const XWin * parent_;...}
```

I'm running into problems when I make a call to the parent class using "parent_"... as in:

```
parent_->setForeground(color);
```

with the (g++) compiler telling me

```
meter.h: In member function ‘void Meter::setForeground(uns)’:
meter.h:72:33: error: passing ‘const XWin’ as ‘this’ argument of \
‘void Xwin::setForeground(long unsigned int)’ discards qualifiers \
 [-fpermissive]
   { parent_->setForeground(color); }
```

How can I tell g++, that "it's ok, the called function isn't modifying "this"?

I'd like to use use 'const' as a declaration of the obvious, that this passed around pointer isn't changed anywhere.  Not sure where to put 'const' to indicate the pointer is not changed (and not have it apply to what is
pointed to, as that MAY change).

Is this possible?

(a non-working example that I tried added after seeing 1st answer :-( )

Note -- I one of the first things I tried before posting here was putting const after the function name and before the argument list as one answer appears to suggest.  Unfortunately, this appears to declare the **object** as const  as well as, or instead of the pointer to the object.  I found this out via:

```
xwin.h: In member function ‘void XWin::done(int) const’:
xwin.h:34:38: error: assignment of member ‘XWin::done_’ in \
read-only object 
   void done( int val ) const { done_ = val; } ;
```

That gave gave me the hint that const in that position applies to the function and doesn't necessarily apply to the pointer (even if it does, I don't want to declare the object constant -- that would be "dubious" at best, calling a method to set a "const object"?  It's the pointer to the object that I want to declare const, not the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ FAQ has the answer here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-ptr-vs-ptr-const.html.

What you’re are asking for is a constant pointer rather than a pointer to a constant.

```
XWin * const parent;
```

There are many useful reasons for having a pointer to a constant. Not so many good reasons for having a constant pointer.

Give some thought to what you hope to achieve by having a constant pointer. Is anyone going to care? Are there optimizations that the compiler can make? Not usually.

Comment: It's 1) a point of sanity, and 2) I hope in the destructor of the 1st object that fills in that pointer to "release" it on object destruction -- which I could likely do anyway, but its a matter, perhaps of unjustified paranoia?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are declaring pointers to const `XWin` objects. That means you cannot modify the objects.

```
Meter::Meter(const XWin * parent,...): parent_(parent) {}
class Meter {...
    const XWin * parent_;...}
```

What you actually want is const pointers to (non-const) `XWin` objects.

```
Meter::Meter(XWin * const parent,...): parent_(parent) {}
class Meter {...
    XWin * const parent_;...}
```

IMO, if you put the const on the right side, instead of the left, it would be simpler to get it right and not mess constant pointers with constant objects.